# Logistic regression with random and with fixed intercept

Tags: regression, logistic, interpretation, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

I have made logistic regression with fixed intercept and with random intercept on the same data, and the results (the odds-ratios) are very different. Could somebody tell me what can be the reasons of these big differences between the two regressions?

Comment: It will be much easier to explain this if you provide more details of both models (in particular: provide both models with a description of the variables at hand)

Comment: Ok, so I have 4 independent variables: sex (0: male, 1: female), age (5-year age groups), residence (county) and working status (0: working, 1: unemployed).The dependent variable is the self-reported health condition (0: good, 1: not good). I made the logistic regressions with fixed intercept and with random intercept (normally-distributed random effect), and, as I wrote, the resulting odds-ratios are very different. The results of the model with random intercept seem much more realistic. What are the possible reasons of this difference? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Well, a probable explication is subject-level heterogeneity.  You did'nt give details so we cannot say much more.

Comment: Do you mean fixed intercept in the sense of a single intercept and no subject-specific effects, or do you mean a fixed effects model?  You used the tag for fixed effects model.